# How do I reverse an floating-point array with size inputted by user in individual function using "for" loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, for-loop

I know there are so many libraries in this code. That's because I was trying everything and also testing some other things. The problem is that function called "wspak" is not outputted well in my main function. I mean, for example, it outputs the first or last index 10 times instead of outputting all 10 indexes once. I hope you all will understand this code, because I use polish appellations for my variables. This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <random>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>  

using namespace std;

float maxitab(int n, float tab[]);                //deklaracja funkcji
float minitab(int n, float tab[]);                //deklaracja funkcji
float wspak(int n, float tab[]);                  //deklaracja funkcji
double rand_double()
{
    return ((double)rand()) / ((double)RAND_MAX);
}
double rand_double_interval(double a, double b)
{
    return rand_double() * (b - a) + a;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n;
    float* tab;
    cout << "Program wyszuka najwiekszy element tablicy.\n";
    cout << "Podaj ilosc elementow tablicy: ";
    cin >> n;
    tab = new float[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        float wylosowane_liczby = rand_double_interval(-1, 1);
        tab[i] = wylosowane_liczby;
    }
    cout << "WYLOSOWANE z przedzialu <-1,1> elementy tablicy to: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << tab[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "\nNajwiekszy WYLOSOWANY z przedzialu <-1,1> element tablicy to: " << maxitab(n, tab);
    cout << "\nNajmniejszy WYLOSOWANY z przedzialu <-1,1> element tablicy to: " << minitab(n, tab);
    cout << "\nTablica od konca do poczatku: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << wspak(n, tab);
    }
    delete[] tab;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
float maxitab(int n, float tab[])                //definicja funkcji 
{
    float maximum = tab[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (tab[i] > maximum)
        {
            maximum = tab[i];
        }
    }
    return maximum;
}
float minitab(int n, float tab[])                //definicja funkcji
{
    float minimum = tab[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (tab[i] <= minimum)
        {
            minimum = tab[i];
        }
    }
    return minimum;
}
float wspak(int n, float tab[])                 //definicja funkcji
{
    float wspak = 0;
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (tab[i] < wspak)
        {
            wspak = tab[i];
        }
    }
    return wspak;
}
```

Comment: If you pass the same parameters to a function 10 times I would expect it to return the same result 10 times. `cout << wspak(n, tab);`

Comment: Program just sits waiting for user input. You should hardcode the input so we're all testing with the same values. You should also add the expected output for that input to the question so that we all know we're chasing the same bug.

Comment: @user4581301 I just copied that wrong and didn't catch it. It is of course in this code.

Comment: Please note that the header `<algorithm>` provides a lot of useful algorithms, like [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element).

Comment: In,  `wspak()` , `float wspak = 0;` --> `float wspak = tab[n-1];`

Comment: @Bob__ I didn't even know about that. But anyway I'm unfortunately supposed to do it in that way.

Comment: Could you please clarify what the last loop in `main` (the one with `cout << wspak(n, tab);`) was supposed to do and why are there all those unused functions?

Comment: @Bob__ The last loop in `main` is supposed to output an array in reverse x times, where x is number of indexes of course. And what do you mean by "all those unused functions"?

Comment: So, in `main` the loop should be `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  { wspak(n, tab);  }` while the function just `void wspak(int n, float tab[]) {  for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) { std::cout << tab[i] << ' '; } std::cout << '\n'; }`?

Comment: @Bob__ Yes, now it outputs all the indexes from last to first, but multiple times.

Comment: @Bob__ Okay, I got it. Now it works perfect. Last `main` for-loop was supposed to be `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)`. Thank you very much for your help and the time you spent on that.

Comment: Well, you wrote "is supposed to output an array in reverse **x times**", but instead it seems you need to print it only **once**, so there's no need for a *loop*, in `main`, just *one* call to `wspack`.

Answer (score 0):

```
float wspak(int n, float tab[]);                  //deklaracja funkcji



wspak(n, tab);



void wspak(int n, float tab[])                 //definicja funkcji
{
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << tab[i] << ' ' << endl;
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Why not just delete `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` since it only iterates once?

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes, you're right.